# Android N - priv app application

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I made an application that should reboot to recovery.
I push it to `priv-app` to let it have the required privileges.
Now when I tested it on `Android 7` I can't reboot (in previous version it worked) 
I see in the log:

> 09-04 13:11:07.791   376   376 E SELinux : avc:  denied  { find } for
>   service=recovery pid=3027 uid=10057
>   scontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768
>   tcontext=u:object_r:recovery_service:s0 tclass=service_manager
>   permissive=0

Is there a new or additional step that should be done to make my app *priv_app* domain and not *platform_app*?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform` from your `Android.mk`, because, for selinux, if an app certificate is "platform", then it'll be in "platform_app" domain.

Otherwise, if certificate is NOT "platform" and is in "priv-app", then selinux will put it in "priv_app" domain.

Check this file: `system/sepolicy/seapp_contexts`

```
user=_app seinfo=platform domain=platform_app type=app_data_file levelFrom=user
user=_app isPrivApp=true domain=priv_app type=app_data_file levelFrom=user
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered bad practice please give a quick blurb to explain what this does.